# Get number of items in content folder in a nuxt blog

Tags: fetch, vue-component, nuxt.js, vuex, nuxt-content

In my Nuxt page I have a navigation component where I try to achieve something like

**[Logo] [Product] [Infos] [Jobs(2)]**

Where (2) is a flag representing the number of items in the corresponding "jobs" content folder.
I tried to fill the state but couldn't get it working. My state looks like this:

```js
export const state = () => ({
  jobsLength: null,
})

export const mutations = {
  setJobsLength(state, payload) {
    state.jobsLength = payload.length
  },
}

export const getters = {
  getJobsLength(state) {
    return state.jobsLength
  },
}

export const actions = {
  async fetch({ $content, commit }) {
    const jobs = await $content('jobs').fetch()
    commit('setJobsLength', jobs.length)
  },
}
```

My Navigation.vue Component:

```html
<a href="/jobs">
    Jobs {{ getJobsLength }}
</a>

....

<script>
import { mapGetters, mapMutations, mapActions } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
      ...mapGetters({
          getJobsLength: 'jobsLength/getJobsLength',
      }),
  },
  mounted() {
      this.fetchJobs()
  },
  methods: {
      ...mapActions({
          fetchJobs: 'jobsLength/fetch',
      }),
  },
}
</script>
```

The response is

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $content is not a function

I feel like I'm missing something but after like 2-3h in the code I'm blind.

Comment: What happens if you `const jobs = await $content('jobs').fetch()` and then, `job.length` inside of you `.vue` component ? Without vuex, directly in your component.

Comment: @kissu I have multiple places/components where I want to use the value (desktop navigation, mobile navigation, footer, etc...)

But in other ways I use your solution right now as I've built a component just for the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is probably coming from the fact that you're passing a number to your commit already (`jobs.length`)

```js
commit('setJobsLength', jobs.length)
```

But in your mutation, you do use `length` **again**. A correct version would be this:

```js
setJobsLength(state, arrayLength) { // better naming, rather than payload
  state.jobsLength = arrayLength
},
```

Also, make it easy for yourself, strip the getter and use the state directly

```js
...mapState('jobsLength', ['jobsLength'])
// btw here the namespaced module should probably be renamed to something more generic like "jobs"
...mapState('jobs', ['jobsLength'])
```

Same goes for your action, why not call it directly `async fetchJobs({ $content, commit })` rather than renaming it afterwards.

Finally, do not forget to make an `async mounted` since your action is `async`

```js
async mounted() {
    await this.fetchJobs()
},
```

---

PS: Vuex can be overkill and complicate things. If you don't need `jobsLength` globally, use a local state.